# Adobe Media Encoder CC2014 SDK / API / WebService

Tags: web-services, api, adobe

I would like to know if it's currently possible to access AME SDK or API ?

I seen binaries named : - ame_webservice_console.exe - AMEWebService.exe (it's a windows service for media trans-coding)

But there isn't any documentation about that. It is implemented or in the roadmap for developers?

I explain the goal : I would like automatically schedule a transcode from a external project throught the AME Webservice without import manually the file by the menu. That's really interesting to mount an external and centralized render farm cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find AMEWinService.exe and AMEWebService.exe inside Adobe Media Encoder CC(inside program files)

The things you have to do

1.Start the **AME windows service** by AMEWinService -install command in your command line(run as administrator)

2.Start the **AME Web service** in the same way

3.Now you can enjoy the service at **localhost:8080** , if you want change this configuration you can done it at **ame_webservice_config.ini** file

4.for client side application development you can refer the below document

https://github.com/sp00x/node-adobe-media-encoder-webservice/blob/master/dist/ame-webservice-client.d.ts

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170163/is-adobe-media-encoder-scriptable-with-extendscript/48907412#48907412